# iOS : round off to nearest number

Tags: ios, numbers, rounding

Lets say I've following `NSInteger`'s :

- 111
- 246
- 99
- 82
- 92
- 85

Is there a function which converts (round off) like these numbers like :

- 110
- 250
- 100
- 80
- 90
- 85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your requested result, numbers less than 100 are rounded to the nearest 5, and those over rounded to the nearest 10. By doing this, you can get the desired result

```
- (NSInteger)roundToNearest:(NSInteger)inputNum
{
    if (inputNum < 100){
        return roundf(inputNum / 5.0f) * 5;
    }
    else {
        return roundf(inputNum / 10.0f) * 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// This Generic function can solve the purpose you can modify it according to your requirement.

```
- (NSInteger)roundOffNumberToNearestCompleteNo:(NSInteger)number
{
    if(number <= 0)
        return 0;

    NSString *strNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",number];

    NSInteger digitCount = [strNumber length];

    if(digitCount == 1)
    {
        if(number <= 5)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 10;
        }
    }

    NSString *strNumberUnit = @"1";

    for(int i = 1; i < digitCount; i++)
    {
        strNumberUnit = [strNumberUnit stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
    }

    NSInteger numberUnit = [strNumberUnit integerValue];

    NSInteger reminder = number%numberUnit;

    if(reminder <= (numberUnit/2))
    {
        number = number -  reminder;
    }
    else
    {
        number = number + (numberUnit - reminder);
    }

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier to implement it yourself:

```
- (NSInteger)roundOff:(NSInteger)number
{
    NSInteger remainder = number % 5;
    NSInteger quotient = number / 5;
    if (remainder > 0) {
        return (quotient + 1) * 5;
    }
    else {
        return quotient * 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
- (NSInteger)roundFive:(NSInteger)number
{
   return roundf(number/5.)*5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a more generic and thus reusable method? This seems to work for all valid NSIntegers including negative numbers and checks for div0 but someone let me know if they spot a flaw:

```
- (NSInteger)roundInteger:(NSInteger)num toNearestInteger:(NSInteger)roundTo
{
    if (!roundTo) { return 0; }
    return (roundTo * round((float)num / roundTo));
}
```